# Powershell Active Directory Module in Remote Session

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-remoting

Hi does anyone have any experience of how to get the Active Directory module to work in a remote ps session?
Nothing I'm trying seems to work. 
My remoting between the computers are fine and working and they are joined to a domain. 
Lets say I do this

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName DC01
Invoke-Command -Session $Session {Import-Module Active Directory}
WARNING: Error initializing default drive: 'Unable to contact the server. This
may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not
 have the Active Directory Web Services running.'.
```

If I logon to the server directly it works fine. Tried creating a SessionConfiguration also and told it to load the AD module but no luck there either.

Comment: Don't you forget the credention in the call to New-PSSession ?

Comment: I just forgot to type it in here, of course I have the -Credentials parameter :) I found the solution to my problem. I enabled CredSSP on the server again from scratch and on my client and now it's working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I enabled CredSSP on the server again from scratch and on my client and now it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

May be the dreaded "double hop authentication" problem.  Since you already have a Session Configuration set up, you can try adding -RunAs to that and see if it starts working:

http://www.vinithmenon.com/2012/11/delegated-administration-in-windows.html